# How can I modify "fetchAll" with certain columns?

Tags: strapi

I want to limit the result of `return strapi.services.myType.fetchAll (ctx.query);` by selecting certain columns (`SELECT column1, column2, ...` not `SELECT *`).

How and where can I edit "ctx.query"?

Many thanks!

P.S. I also do not know exactly how to use GraphQL (for backend) for this case. Can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: Could this be the answer to my question? I have not tested it yet.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647775/how-do-i-return-only-selected-certain-fields-in-strapi?rq=1

Comment: If I use GraphQL and have the following GraphQL query, how and where can I place this query in the backend?
`{
  posts {
    id,
    title
  }
}`

Comment: Is GraphQL a frontend application? I have in the table (ContentType) columns that should be invisible to the users. If I use GraphQL in my frontend, could the GraphQL-query be manipulated? I mean, can any user hack these columns?


If I just want to show `{
posts {
  col1,
  col2
}
}`, but the user change this like `{
posts {
  col3,
  col4,
colAnyone...
}
}`

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes when using `GraphQL` any API user can select any existing columns, as long as s/he knows the column name (and has access to the API). Technically `GraphQL` allows you to restrict the access to some fields/columns but I guess that's out of `Strapi` scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in several ways, one of which is in your model's lifecycle function `afterFetchAll()`. It should work whether you're using GraphQL or not.

```
afterFetchAll: async (model, response, options) => {
    model.forEach(m => {
        m.unset('column1')
        m.unset('column2')
    })
}
```

This way you will be able to remove any columns/fields from the fetched model array.

And this file should be located in: api/MyType/models/MyType.js

Ref to [here](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/models.html#life-cycle-callbacks) for more information.

Comment: Many Thanks for pointing out, I will test it this week and report it afterwards.:)

Comment: I don't think if this is efficient way of doing it, it will first fetch all the records and then you are removing the columns by loop!!!